# How to render search results only when the user press search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Does anyone know how to only display search results once you have clicked the search button?

At the moment, my page is currently displaying  everything from my @flights.each. But I only want this information to become visible once they have clicked search :)

my index.html.erb

```
<h1>Flights#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/flights/index.html.erb</p>





From Airport:
<%= form_for(flights_index_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :from_airport_id, params[:from_airport_id] %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>

<% @flights.each do |f| %>
<br>
<br>

    Flight from <%= f.from_airport_id %>
    Arriving at <%= f.to_airport_id %>
<% end %>
```

my controller

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    if params[:from_airport_id]
      @flights = Flight.where('from_airport_id LIKE ?', "%#{params[:from_airport_id]}%")
    else
      @flights = Flight.all
    end
  end


  private
    def flights_path
      params.require(:flight).permit(:flight, :from_airport_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because you have `@flights = Flight.all` in the `else` condition. When there is no query(such as after hitting the submit button and passing over the params) it will default to show all the flights. I'd take this line out and only have

```
def index

    if params[:from_airport_id]
      @flights = Flight.where('from_airport_id LIKE ?', "%#{params[:from_airport_id]}%")
    else
      @flights = []
    end
  end
```

Or you can look to have an AJAX request from your flights search and render the form that way.

Comment: let me know if this doesn't work or if you have other questions!